# Play DVD movie using Parole

Tags: video-player

I have installed parole DVD player and would like to watch a movie. When I start parole it is not clear how to load and start the movie.  The movie is a dvd purchased from the store. How do I start the movie using parole?

Comment: You will probably need to install in case if the disc is protected: 
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4 &&

sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh &&

sudo apt-get install libdvdcss2

Comment: Why Parole and why not VLC or mplayer or others?

Answer (score 0):

It works although the Insert Disc menu item is still grey. To Play, click  `Open Location` and put there `dvd:///dev/sr0` . Also be sure you might need to have next previously installed:

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4 
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh 
sudo apt-get install libdvdcss2
```